# Parsing XML with <![CDATA[ is giving wrong result and null

Tags: soap-api, xml

I am trying to parse an XML with ![CDATA where multiple attributes are embedded into ![CDATA tags. By referring to multiple suggestions on parsing XML with CDATA, I have implemented below sample code to parse the xml and read the content in CDATA.

```
        String responseString =res.getBody();
        responseString = responseString.replaceAll( '<!\\[CDATA\\[', '' );
        responseString = responseString.replaceAll( ']]>', '' );
        DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
        doc.load(responseString);
        DOM.XmlNode node=doc.getRootElement();

       if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT) {
            if(node.getName()=='IndexDetails'){
                 List<Dom.XMLNode>  childNodes  =node.getChildren();
                
                for(Dom.XMLNode childNode : childNodes ){
                    
                 System.debug('*** getName '+childNode.getName());
                 System.debug('*** getText '+childNode.getText());
                }
                
            }
        }
```

with above logic I am trying to find the values of XMM_DCN1 , XMM_WRDTE1 but when I use getName I am getting 'null' for all nodes and getText is giving a wrong values as below.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

XML reference

```
<IndexDetails><![CDATA[<DOCUMENT>
    <FIELD>
    <NAME>XMM_DCN1</NAME>
    <VALUE>sdfsdfsfd</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <NAME>XMM_WRDTE1</NAME>
    <VALUE></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <NAME>XMM_Ssdf</NAME>
    <VALUE>23/01/2017</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <NAME>XMM_DOCID1</NAME>
    <VALUE>657551</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <FILENAME>sdfsdf.pdf</FILENAME>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD><PAGES>2</PAGES></FIELD>
    </DOCUMENT>]]></IndexDetails>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your `CDATA` Removal, it's just that you needed to one level deeper before trying to get the names and values of the notes.

Each `FIELD` node actually has 2 more nodes - `NAME` and `VALUE`.

```
String responseString =res.getBody();
responseString = responseString.replaceAll( '<!\\[CDATA\\[', '' );
responseString = responseString.replaceAll( ']]>', '' );
DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
doc.load(responseString);
DOM.XmlNode node=doc.getRootElement();

if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT) {
  if(node.getName()=='IndexDetails'){
    
    DOM.XmlNode documentNode = node.getChildElement('DOCUMENT', null);
    List<Dom.XMLNode>  childNodes  = documentNode.getChildren();
    
    //children of "DOCUMENT"
    for(Dom.XMLNode childNode : childNodes ){
      
      List<Dom.XMLNode>  childChildNodes  = childNode.getChildren();
      
      //children of "FIELD"
      for(Dom.XMLNode childChildNode : childChildNodes ){
        System.debug('*** getName '+ childChildNode.getName());
        System.debug('*** getText '+ childChildNode.getText());
      }
    }
      
  }
}
```

You were trying to get the name and value of the `FIELD` node - which it doesn't have. It has 2 more child nodes instead.

Comment: Hi Caspar, thanks for your inputs. I have tried updating the logic accordingly and see      DOM.XmlNode documentNode = node.getChildElement('DOCUMENT', null);
 is returning null, only node.getChildren() is returning document node along with other children as below.  (XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,<,], XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,DOCUMENT>. Do you see anything else I could do to crack this? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I added the 5 lines you had in your code at the top - I'd left them off to make it more concise, but perhaps that was confusing. The above code I've actually run and can confirm that it works.

Comment: thanks much for the details, some how surprisingly I am still not able to crack this as while trying to get DOCUMENT node running into null pointer exception and  node getChildren is giving  return as (XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,<,], XMLNode[TEXT,null,null,null,null,null,DOCUMENT>

Comment: @Rajasekhar - I am facing a similar issue. You were able to fix the issue?